# Do I need provide Gpu context when creating unified memory?

Tags: cuda, unified-memory, cuda-context

Question 1)

When I call CUDA driver API, usually I need first push the context (which represents a GPU runtime) to current thread. For normal `cuMalloc`, the memory will be allocated on that GPU specified by the context. But if I try to call `cuMallocManaged` to create unified memory, do I still need to push a GPU context?

Question 2)

Say I have 2 GPUs, each has 1 GB DRAM. So can I allocate unified memory of 2 GB? with each GPU holds half of it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Follow established driver API programming methods.  Explicitly establish a CUDA context.
2. No, this is not how managed memory works.  A managed allocation is visible, in its entirety, to all GPUs in the system.  This is true whether we are talking about a pre-pascal UM regime or a pure-pascal UM regime, although the specific method of visibility varies.  Refer to the programming guide sections on [UM with multi-GPU](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-multi-gpu).

Comment: In the url you pointed out, it says: for pre-sm60 device, the current active device is the home for the physical allocation, is that also true for sm >= 6.0? Which means, one allocation can only be done in one GPU, but can be accessed from other GPUs. Then if I have 2 GPUs, each has 1 GB, the max size of unified memory I can allocate is 1 GB, not 2GB.

Comment: The link says that for cc 6.0 and higher, the allocation will be migrated to the GPU in question, as needed.  The UM allocation is *visible to* (i.e. *mapped to*) each GPU in the system, and it will be migrated to any GPU on-demand, i.e. when that GPU generates a page fault against that item, or when that item is explicitly moved e.g. via a `cudaMemPrefetchAsync` command.

Comment: Thanks, I read the document, so for sm60 and above, the system handles where the physical memory located. But then, if I call `cudaMallocManaged`, why should I still push a context first? Or I can use any context? I'm asking because context is created on one GPU, for two gpus, you will have 2 contexts, then which one should I use for unified memory allocation?